# Vim get/set buffer name without entering buffer

Tags: vim

You can change the name of a buffer with the 'file' command, but you have to enter the buffer first.
How can I use the getbufvar/setbufvar or a similar function to get/change the name of a buffer by just providing a buffer number, without entering it? Is there a way at all?

Comment: I know getbufinfo() gives you the buffer name in a variable called 'name', so I tried something like this: setbufvar(buffer_number, 'name', 'new_name_value'), but it just creates a b:name variable. Is there a specific way to address the buffer name?

Comment: not possible as far as i know with pure Vimscript. Might work using python Interface.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a native way of changing a buffer name, but restoring the current buffer is not a complicated task:

```
function! Rename(buffer, name)
  let current = bufnr("%")
  execute a:buffer . 'bufdo file ' . fnameescape(a:name)
  execute 'buffer ' . current
endfunction
```

Comment: You should probably escape `a:name` somehow.

Comment: @Maëlan well noticed. Thanks.